# How to get C++ to perform I/O from a USB Port like a Serial Port

Tags: c++, usb

Is it possible to read/write from/to a specific USB port, avoiding all that USB handshaking stuff?

What I want to do is communicate with a microcontroller, for example, that doesn't have a USB driver on board via USB. I want my C++ application to be able to send data via a specific USB port and then to receive data from that same USB port.

Basically what I want to be able to do is treat that USB port like a serial port. Is this possible? Is there a workaround I can use?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know this isn't the best way to go about communication with a uC, but let's assume, for some reason, I have to do it this way.

Edit: BTW I'm using Windows 7

Comment: This depends on the operating system/kernel that you're using; C++ does not provide a standard interface for this kind of thing directly.

Comment: You bought the wrong microcontroller, you cannot talk to it without spending money.  Find an old scrap machine with a serial port.

Comment: This is purely a hardware issue, not software. You cannot connect a USB bus to an MCU without a USB controller without some kind of adapter. The cheapest kind of adapter is one that provides a serial/UART port. If that's too much, then you're SOL.

Comment: @Delan: What makes you think the USB controller hardware on a typical PC can be used in the way he wants to use it?  I think this is a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the USB to serial port adapters. The USB port will look just like a serial port to your C++ program.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I assumed the microcontroller had a serial port, not a USB port.

Comment: The microcontroller has a serial port (well I can use a couple of I/O ports as a serial port), not a USB port. There are a number of adapters I could use but here in New Zealand they are rediculously overpriced for the project I am doing.

Comment: @Jonagik - while not wishing to advertise on SO http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-to-rs232-serial-port-adapter-transparent-green-245120 might help

Answer (score 4):

The usual solution is to use an FTDI USB-to-serial chip, such as the [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm), on your microcontroller board. Then, as far as your MCU is concerned, it's talking to a serial port, and on the host machine you just have to have the right drivers.

On my Mac, the FTDI chip shows up as a serial port at `/dev/tty.usbmodem____`, where `____` is some persistent unique ID assigned by the Mac on first detection. Unplugging and replugging, even weeks later, gets the same number, but it's a different number on a different Mac.

On Windows, it shows up as a new `COM` port if you have the drivers installed, IIRC. On Linux, it shows up as `/dev/ttyUSB_` where `_` is a serial number starting at 0, if you have FTDI serial driver support enabled in the kernel. This can get tricky if you plug in more than one FTDI chip.

If your microcontroller has a built-in USB port, then you need to find the software for it to identify itself as a standard CDC (Communication Device Class) serial port device ([standard documentation available](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/CDC1.2_WMC1.1_012011.zip)). Most OSs have support for this standard USB device class.

Comment: Thanks for your response. USB-to-serial chips are overpriced here in New Zealand for the type of project I'm doing and my device doesn't have a USB port itself. What I want to do is communicate over a specific USB port rather than having windows decide which port based on the device's VID/PID.

Comment: @JonaGik, i do not know what you consider too expensive, but you can get an FTDI chip from digikey (NZ) for 5.66 (NZ$).

Comment: DigiKey FTW. @JonaGik: You want to tie your code to a single, physical port? That's very much not recommended, and not how the protocol is designed. We had a JTAG debugger that did that back at work and we dumped it first chance we got.

Comment: DigiKey has great prices but the shipping is prohibitive unless the order is more than US$120

Comment: @Mike I know its not recommended but lets says its my only option. How would I do it?

Comment: @Jona: I have no idea, but I'd start figuring it out by reading the USB 2.0 specifications. And you are not going to be able to avoid having to write your own driver, since you'll need to monkey with the handshake process in order to not lose track of the physical port.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can do a close approximation of this using the HID interface: drivers are built in, and you can send feature reports in both directions. It isn't quite serial port simplicity (since it is packets, as opposed to a continuous byte stream) but [hidapi](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) makes it really simple and cross-platform.

Comment: My device doesn't have a vendor and product ID (which hidapi seems to require).

Comment: If it is a USB device, it kind of HAS to have a vendor and product ID. You may not know what they are, but if you have a working, functioning USB device you have a vendor ID and product ID.

Comment: It isn't a "USB Device" - it's an off-the-shelf microcontroller. What I want to do is communicate with my computer via a couple of its I/O ports. My computer only has USB ports so I was wondering if I could just get my computer to communicate via a specific port rather than to a VID/PID (with Windows deciding which port the device is on). I know there are USB to serial adapters one can buy which accomplish this (they have a VID/PID) but I was wondering if I could accomplish this with software rather than hardware.

Comment: Also, on Windows, there's an .ini file you have to install somewhere which declares your device's VID/PID and what driver it needs. I don't have the details beyond that, though; you could look at the "drivers" that FTDI installs and work from there.

Comment: Ah, no: there is no way for you to run wires from your microcontroller into the USB pins and obtain any kind of meaningful communication. OS level communication requires a driver, a driver requires USB compliance, and USB compliance requires a VID/PID along with a USB serial engine of some kind (which is what the USB to serial adapters provide). I'd suggest buying a microcontroller with the USB hardware support built in (Silicon Labs makes good instances) and using HID: no driver installs necessary and they provide nicely working firmware in source form.